# Update plotly plot as form data gets entered in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

js newbie here. I'm attempting to create an interactive plot on a webpage that looks like the below. Can I have a plot update when the values in the fields are changed?

[image]

my js code looks like:

```
function generate_x(low, high) {
  var x = [];
  for (var i = low; i <= high; i++) {
      x.push(i);
  }
  return x;
}
function f1(x, n_beds){
  //do something
  var y = x
  return y;
}
function f2(x, n_beds){
  //do something
  var y = x
  return y;
}

var v1 = document.getElementById("v1").value;
var v2 = document.getElementById("v2").value;
var v3 = document.getElementById("v3").value;
var v4 = document.getElementById("v4").value;

var x = generate_x(0, 100)
var trace1 = {
  x: x,
  y: f1(x, n_beds),
  type: "scatter"
};
var trace2 = {
  x: x,
  y: f2(x, n_beds),
  type: "scatter"
};
Plotly.newPlot("plot", data);
```

Comment: Are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: @tnk479 yep, jquery is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people use jquery to make this easier to implement. I can't see your HTML but I am assumign that the variables v1, v2, v3, and v4 correspond to the four text inputs in your screenshot above. So, jquery lets you handle events like change. You can update the PLotly data inside of the function you code to handle the change event on  your inputs.

```
$("#v1").change(function () {
   //Update your Plotly data here...
}
```

Comment: this might be pedantic, but where would the above code go? is it between `<script></script>` tags in html or within a separate script file?

Comment: Also can I condition this function on something else? for example, if all four fields are filled and one of them is changed, do x.

Comment: And one more thing, this works, but only when I hit enter on a field. Is it possible that that graph updates as I type?

Comment: I did some googling and figured it out. I used `$("#v1,#v2,#v3").on("input", plotter)`. I also stuck all the plotting code in a function called `plotter`.